# Alternative to Java Applets for applications that require hardware or local file access

Tags: java, flash, web-applications

Are there any alternatives to Java Applets (or Web starts) and Flash (or Silverlight) for a browser application that allows file access / hardware access to client machine?

Java and Flash/Silverlight both have deficiencies that makes them unfeasible solutions for my projects.

Are there any new technologies for this purpose, that are not yet popular but might be so in the near future?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Can HTML5 access hardware/OS resources including the file system, cause if it can, I'm not using it 8O

Comment: *"Are there any new technologies for this purpose, that are not yet popular but might be so in the near future?"* - A web application that can access my file system/computer hardware - I bloody well hope not. There's a reason why the current technologies work the way they do

Comment: HTML5 can access the filesystem _if you allow it to_. The restrictions are fairly strict - i.e. the user has to give it a file handle. But depending on what you want to access HTML5 allows for saving files to an unspecified "temporary storage" without user permission. As far as access to hardware, this is very vague. What hardware, to what end? Netflix uses HTML5 to show 1080p video which uses hardware acceleration.

Comment: @MadProgrammer forgot to tag you - see above.

Comment: @BoristheSpider The video support, is, obvious, a in built support of the new "video", access to the hardware would come down o the implementation, remember Adobe and Apples bickering about Flash performance, which Adobe put den to Apples reluctance o provide direct access to the hardware, so it would be implementation specific. File access (save/upload) is pretty much support since early versions of HTML. Not sure that this is what the op is after, but the details are thin :P

Answer (score 0):

No there's no technology right now or even in the future that would be allowed to do that from a web browser. Such a technology would allow all hackers to take control of all personal computers without passing any check.